# Perl, Reading dir and getting stat() for each file

Tags: perl, stat, opendir

In Perl, When I'm trying to read `dir` in a loop, and perform `for each file stat()`  in order to get `$size` and `$mode`, I get wrong data!

For example, I just created simple text file and it shows me it has permission 0000 and no size.

Perl Code:

```
if (!@ARGV[0]) {
    die("Za mało parametrów!\n");
}

$dirname = @ARGV[0];

opendir(DIR, $dirname) || die("Nie mogę otworzyć katalogu!\n");
while( $filename = readdir(DIR) ) {

    ($dev,$ino,$mode,$nlink,$uid,$gid,$rdev,$size,
         $atime,$mtime,$ctime,$blksize,$blocks) = stat($filename);

    $perm = sprintf("%04o", $mode & 07777);
    $tmp1 = int(($size/1024));
    $tmp2 = length($filename);

    if (($tmp1 > $tmp2) && ($perm =~ /.[^5410]../)) {
        print("$filename\n");
    }
}
closedir(DIR);
```

Comment: You should always enable warnings when developing Perl code (then change @ARGV[0] to $ARGV[0]). The solution to your problem is given in the second paragraph of the docs for the readdir() function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will need to pass the full filepath to the stat() function. At the moment you are just passing a filename, so the script will look in its current directory for this file.

In other words, do this:

```
($dev,$ino,$mode,$nlink,$uid,$gid,$rdev,$size,
         $atime,$mtime,$ctime,$blksize,$blocks) = stat("$dirname/$filename");
```

Comment: You really should use `catfile` from `File::Spec::Functions` rather than manually concatenating a directory. Further you probably want to probably want to use `abs_path` from `Cwd` as well once you've gone this far.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by others, the problem is that you are trying to operate on files in `$dirname` with only the file name (as per the `readdir` documentation). Without the full path, `stat` cannot find the file.

One could concatenate the directory to each file name and perhaps even make the result absolute (see my comment to the other answer), but this is a pain in the neck.

The other way to operate on files in `$dirname` is to change the working directory to the directory in question, operate and then return to the original. My favorite way to `cd` is the `File::chdir` module, which creates the scalar `$CWD` which is tied to the current working directory. This does exactly what I described when it is made `local` to a block and changed to your directory in question. Then you can do something like:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use File::chdir;

$dirname = shift @ARGV or die("Za mało parametrów!\n") ;

{
    local $CWD = $dirname; #changes the cwd to contents of $dirname

    opendir(my $dir, $CWD) || die("Nie mogę otworzyć katalogu!\n");
    while( $filename = readdir($dir) ) {

        ($dev,$ino,$mode,$nlink,$uid,$gid,$rdev,$size,
             $atime,$mtime,$ctime,$blksize,$blocks) = stat($filename);

        $perm = sprintf("%04o", $mode & 07777);
        $tmp1 = int(($size/1024));
        $tmp2 = length($filename);

        if (($tmp1 > $tmp2) && ($perm =~ /.[^5410]../)) {
            print("$filename\n");
        }
    }

}
```

After the block, the original `cwd` is restored. Note: I have not tested this code for this case. I use this method often. It should fix the problem, and it's portable!